# Why do different URLs pass `toBeEqual()`?

Tags: url, jestjs

This test fails for me but clearly the URLs are unequal. Thoughts?

```
it('should have working URL comparisons', () => {
  const a = new URL('http://foo.example.com');
  const b = new URL('http://bar.example.com');
  expect(b).not.toEqual(a);
});
```

(using jest@27.5.1)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KajktIe — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: This will depend mostly on you `testEnvironment`. For example, using `jsdom`, `expect(b).toEqual(a)` passes, but in `node`, `expect(b).toEqual(a)` does not pass.

If you `console.log(global.URL.toString());` you will get different `URL` implementations if you switch between `node` and `jsdom` environments.

Now, as to why `expect(b).toEqual(a)` passes in `jsdom`, I have no idea..

Comment: thanks, @doublethink - truly odd behavior but at least I'm not crazy (well, maybe not...). I was certainly surprised by the [incorrect?] behavior.

Comment: I would say this is more a case of "it's not a bug, it's a feature"; `jsdom` tries to replicate the browser's "environment" so we can run "browser's" code in node. Maybe the implementation of URL is like this for a good reason. I don't know enough of it to have an opinion on it :)